# Strange results with a range index for a vector in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a k-windsor median function in R.

```
winsor <- function(x, k) {
   stopifnot(is.numeric(x))
   stopifnot(all.equal(k, as.integer(k)))
   n = length(x)
   # cat("N is: ", n)
   stopifnot(k <= (n-1)/2)
   # cat("x[k+1] is: ", x[k+1])
   x[1:k] <- x[k+1]
   # cat("x[1:k] is: ", x[1:k])
   # cat("x[n-k] is: ", x[n-k])
   x[n-k+1:n] <- x[n-k]
   # cat("x[n-k+1:n] is: ", x[n-k+1:n])
   # cat(x)
   mean(x)
}
```

**I am executing this instruction:**

```
winsor(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),3)
```

**x[n-k+1:n]** is:  7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7

**should be:** 7 7 7

making for my function calculating wrong results

Anybody knows why x[8:10] is producing such strange results?

Thanks!

Comment: put parentises at x index. x[(n-k+1):n].

Comment: @Athos that worked. I would be happy to accept your answer as the official one. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put parentheses at x index.

```
x[(n-k+1):n]
```

The operator `:` precedes the arithmatic ones ([see this for details](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Syntax.html)).

[]'s